# как кэшировать из Laravel в Redis чтобы работала пагинация?

Tags: laravel, redis

```
//Так все кешиться но пагинация не рабоатет т.е клацаешь на страницу а показывается все равно закешенная которая первая на которрой 10 записей
$painters = Cache::remember('painters', $minutes, function (){
            return Painter::where('status', '1')->paginate(10);
        });
```

Comment: Добавлять в ключ номер страницы как вариант `Cache::remember('painters.' . $request->page ?? 1, $ttl, $callback);`

Comment: Walfter  спасибо